# Equivalent of python bytestring representation in C++

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, c++11, byte

I need to send a bytecode command over a socket to a DAQ to begin reading out the data. I have implemented this in python by doing something along the lines of: `socket.send(b'$RBH\r')`. I am wondering if the equivalent of this in C++ (or C) would be to send a character array over a socket in the same fashion. More explicitly is the representation of `char byt[] = "$RBH\r"` in C++/C equivalent to `byt = b'$RBH\r'` in python?

Also according to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/ the way in which I declared `byt` in C++/C adds a null character (`\0`) at the end. I assume this would have no effect on the carriage return character (`\r`) in terms of sending data over the socket, am I mistaken? *Maybe this second part can't be answered without more knowledge of the system*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Equivalent" is really not a good word to use. Certainly you can write code in C++ using the `char byt[] = "$RBH\r"` that performs the equivalent function as your python example. You can also write incorrect code.

Comment: Maybe equivalent was a poor word choice. Is it fair to assume that if the socket endpoint expects bytecode that it will treat the character array representation of the message in the same way as the python bytestring?

Comment: I also don't like the word "bytecode"; the term I'm familiar with is "bytes" which is the way data is sent over a network and is what is contained in the python bytes object `b'$RBH\r'`. The way the peer treats these bytes is entirely up to the peer, and must be specified in order to communicate with the peer.

Comment: I think I understand. Just to be sure the python byte object `byt=b'$RBH\r'` corresponds to the representation of each of those characters as a byte, so in decimal it would be [36,82,66,72,13]. Is a character array just the ASCII representation of these same values?